# why L6565 has input range of 80v-240v? Why not 12v-240v?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, adapter, flyback

L6565 Data sheet specifies that input range starts from 80v to wide range. Why the range does not start from 12v? Is it possible to make it to input from 12v and up?

Answer (score 1):

This device has been designed to work as a controller for off-line power supplies. Depending on where you live, the line is 230v or 120v. As a convenience to the user, it will run on either voltage without adjustment. This saves a switch. It also avoids the hazard of a user accidentally connecting a 120v input unit to a 230v mains supply.

If a power supply uses this part, it will draw twice as much current at the lower voltage to maintain the same power throughput. This is a fairly straightforward ratio for a designer to allow for.

It is always easier to design an IC, any circuit for that matter, to run over a small range of voltages. There are no practical mains supplies at voltages lower than 120v, so there is no commercial incentive to make it work below 80v. Setting the minimum voltage at 80v allows the IC designers all sorts of short-cuts and simplifications that would not be possible with a 12v minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The chip is for power factor correction and runs on a DC supply typically 21 volts but can go as low as the under-voltage-lock-out voltage point (about 10.2 volts typically). It doesn't run from 85V to 240V but can orrect the power factor on AC supplies in that range.

The 80V range covers extreme low operating voltages sometimes seen on some islands in Japan (from what I've heard these can go below 100V AC a lot of the time).

So, yes it can run from 12V (DC) but your question is unclear as to whether **you** are specifying AC or DC voltages.

Comment: It is 12v DC. I intend to use it like this, 220vAC default, when line fails,goes back to 12VDC.Output is always 5VDC/3watt. Thank-you so much.